# Freeform Pro: hidden fieldtype - Default Incoming Data stopped working

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I recently updated to EE 2.7.3 (from EE 2.5.5) and Freeform Pro 4.1.3. I had a couple fields using the hidden fieldtype. These fields have the Default Incoming Data set as follows:

```
{exp:stash:get name="date" dynamic="yes" match="#^\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}$#"}
```

Basically what this does is fetch a date from the url query string, see if it matches the proper format, and if so set the default value. This was working prior to the update.

Since the update, it stopped working. I tried to figure out why and here's what I came up with. First, I thought maybe it was a Stash bug. So I var_dump'ed `ee()->TMPL->tagproper` in the `Stash::get` method. And it revealed something interesting:

```
{exp:stash:get name=&quot;date&quot; dynamic=&quot;yes&quot; match=&quot;#^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$#&quot;}
```

It seems that something in the EE 2.6 or 2.7 update caused the quotes (double and single) to get HTML encoded. The brackets did not get encoded so I don't think it was run through `htmlentities`. So my guess is that Freeform needs to decode those entities prior to printing out that default value to screen.

Is this a bug?